# Excel formula to determine if any cells in a range contain a value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

This is probably quite a basic thing to do, but I've been looking around the internet and have tried several ways of doing it to no avail. 
This is my spreadsheet
A1 - Blank  A2 - Text  A3 - Boolean  A4 - Boolean  A5 - Boolean
Cells A3, A4 and A5 contain true or false. Is it possible to return a value of true or false in cell A1 if any of A3, A4 and A5 contain true at least once, or false if they all contain false?

Many thanks if you are able to help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider..................:

```
=OR(A3:A5)
```

Comment: How can this be done on-the-fly? `=OR(A3:A5 > 5)` is an error

Comment: Best way? `=countif(A3:A5, ">5") > 0`?

Comment: @MichaelChirico Looks interesting!

Answer (score 4):

Use this formula for this purpose:

```
=OR(A2:A5)
```